# What to do with old SSD?

Tags: ssd

im about to update my macbook pro SSD (https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015) because i really need the extra 500GB...

Since my current one is fine, I got into thinking on ways to give it an extra-life...

How can i re-propouse my old one? Can I turn it into an external drive? use it as a secondary disk on another machine?

Comment: for all SSD types (SATA, mSATA, M2) you should get USB 3.0 enclosures. connect it to the device to store data on it . use it as a large USB drive to carry data to/from friends.

Answer (score 1):

That link you gave goes to a page that lists an upgrade kit that includes not only the new flash drive (which looks like a bare memory stick circuit board with the connectors on the short edge), but also includes a cute aluminum external enclosure to turn the old SSD stick into an external drive.

Comment: i don't think i can buy only the "shell" though...

Comment: @Leonardo It's clear from the text that that's exactly what they're selling in the kit: The new SSD stick, the external enclosure (just the shell and minimal electronics; you need to provide your own memory stick to put in it), and the tools to allow you to install remove the old stick from your computer, put it in the external enclosure, and install the new stick in your computer.